# How to check a NPM package for non-javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, compilation, npm

Is it possible to check if a npm package contains pure javascript, and no bindings, or dependencies that need compiling?

For example, node-speaker (https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker) needs compiling (mpg321), whereas request (https://github.com/request/request) doesn't, as it only wraps native node.js functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like look for node-gyp in the package.json. Though you would have to do some fancy logic for checking up the dependency graph, since a package might require another package that links against native code. This wouldn't be 100% foolproof, but it's a start.